# I want to convert GMT time to UTC which is 5.30 hour down to local time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two time fields on a form from which i'm storing time.
The first challenge was to keep the time in a particular format.My time format is 12 hour format so if user system is of 24 hour format time then this will convert to 12 hour formt.
Now when i'm storing this time to salesforce it is not correct' I'm getting right time on console but in salesforce it is 5.30 hour back.
How i can convert this time to utc format.

I have tried this

```
       var starthours = Number(fromTime.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
            var startminutes = Number(fromTime.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
            var endhours = Number(toTime.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
            var endminutes = Number(toTime.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
            console.log('starthours '+starthours);
            console.log('startminutes '+startminutes);
            console.log('endhours '+endhours);
            console.log('endminutes '+endminutes);
            
            startTime = (starthours > 12) ? (starthours-12 + ':' + 
          startminutes + ':00'+' PM') : (starthours + ':' + startminutes + 
      ':00' +' AM');
            endTime = (endhours > 12) ? (endhours-12 + ':' + endminutes + 
          ':00'+' PM') : (endhours + ':' + endminutes + ':00'+' AM');

            console.log('startTime '+startTime);
            console.log('endTime '+endTime);

          
            let fromDateTime = fromDate+'T'+startTime;

            let strDate = new Date(fromDateTime);
            console.log('strDate  : '+strDate);

            strDate.setHours(strDate.getHours() - 5);
            strDate.setMinutes(strDate.getMinutes() - 30);
            let strartDate = strDate.toUTCString();
            console.log('fromDateTime  : '+fromDateTime);
            console.log('strartDate  : '+strartDate);
            lstcharges.push(strartDate);     

            let toDateTime = toDate+'T'+endTime;

            let endDate = new Date(toDateTime);
            console.log('endDate  : '+endDate);

            endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours() - 5);
            endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() - 30);
            let enDate = endDate.toUTCString();
            console.log('endDate  : '+endDate);
            console.log('enDate  : '+enDate);

          
            console.log('toDateTime  : '+enDate);
            lstcharges.push(enDate);
```

Comment: Salesforce stores all DateTime values as GMT, are you referencing a [Time field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5) (it's a newer field type, it only includes time)? In the time field, there's no way for Salesforce to know what timezone the time is so it accepts a lot of different inputs (e.g. 12:00, 18:00, 5:55 AM). It is likely _not_ a good solution for what you're trying to do and it especially makes representing times in other timezones difficult if not impossible. If you're not doing that, _how_ are you getting this time value from SF?

Comment: I m getting this time value as   let crDate = new Date(expenseQueryResult.rows[i].createddate);
                crDate.setHours(crDate.getHours() + 5);
                crDate.setMinutes(crDate.getMinutes() + 30);
                let strDate = crDate.toLocaleString();